# Python 2.7/Windows: ttk combobox dropdown shows up underneath topmost root window

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, ttk

I'm experimenting with the new ttk Tile enhancements that ship with Python 2.7.

Windows 7: The code below demonstrates how the combobox dropdown shows up BEHIND our root window when the root window is configured as a topmost window ("always on top"). If you comment out the line """    root.attributes( '-topmost', 1 )""" then the combobox dropdown appears within the root window (as expected).

Anyone have any workarounds for this behavior so we can use comboboxes with 'topmost' windows?

```
# sample code that illustrates problem described above

import Tkinter as tkinter
import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

panelCombo = ttk.Frame( root )
panelCombo.pack( side='top', fill='x', padx=12, pady=8 )
valCombo = ( 'cat', 'dog', 'pig' )
varCombo = tkinter.StringVar()
varCombo.set( 'fish' )
cboCombo = ttk.Combobox( panelCombo, values=valCombo, textvariable=varCombo )
cboCombo.pack( side='left', anchor='w', padx=12, pady=8 )

# make our window 'alwaysontop'
root.attributes( '-topmost', 1 )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=112997&aid=1939129&group_id=12997) in the `Tk` toolkit. It was fixed in [release 8.5.6](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-tcltk/254/). Maybe you just need to wait until that release makes its way into Python.